# Check if a filename has a string in it

Tags: bash, shell

I'm having problems creating an `if` statement to check the files  in my directory for a certain string in their names.

For example, I have the following files in a certain directory:

```
file_1_ok.txt
file_2_ok.txt
file_3_ok.txt
file_4_ok.txt
other_file_1_ok.py
other_file_2_ok.py
other_file_3_ok.py
other_file_4_ok.py
another_file_1_not_ok.sh
another_file_2_not_ok.sh
another_file_3_not_ok.sh
another_file_4_not_ok.sh
```

I want to copy all files that contain `1_ok` to another directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
directory1=/FILES/user/directory1/
directory2=/FILES/user/directory2/


string="1_ok"
cd $directory

for every file in $directory1
do
    if [$string = $file]; then
        cp $file $directory2
    fi
done
```

UPDATE:

The simpler answer was made by [Faibbus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41506920/6136214), but refer to [Inian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41507464/6136214) if you want to remove or simply move files that don't have the specific string you want.

The other answers are valid as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
cp directory1/*1_ok* directory2/
```

Comment: Even simpler than `find`. +1

Comment: @hex2mgl `find` is useful if there are too many matching files to fit on a single command line; you should undelete your answer.

Comment: i got another questions, what if i want to remove every file from the directory except the ones who contain the "1_ok" string?

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man: Refer my update, with `ext glob` enabled at the last, foe delete option.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man: or you can go with:
`find .  -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "*1_ok*" -delete`

Answer (score 4):

Use `find` for that:

```
find directory1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*1_ok*' -exec cp -v {} directory2 \;
```

The advantage of using `find` over the [glob solution posted by Faibbus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41506920/171318) is that it can deal with an unlimited number of files which contain `1_ok` were the glob solution will lead to an `argument list too long` error when calling `cp` with too many arguments.

Conclusion: For interactive use with a limited number of input files the glob will be fine, for a shell script, which has to be stable, I would use `find`.

Answer (score 3):

With your script I suggest:

```
#!/bin/bash

source="/FILES/user/directory1"
target="/FILES/user/directory2"

regex="1_ok"

for file in "$source"/*; do
  if [[ $file =~ $regex ]]; then
    cp -v "$file" "$target"
  fi
done
```

---

From `help [[`:

> When the `=~` operator is used, the string to the right of the operator
>       is matched as a regular expression.

---

Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

Using `extglob` matching in `bash` with the below pattern,

> +(pattern-list)
>   Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns.

First enable `extglob` by

```
shopt -s extglob
cp -v directory1/+(*not_ok*)  directory2/
```

An example,

```
$ ls *.sh
another_file_1_not_ok.sh    another_file_3_not_ok.sh
another_file_2_not_ok.sh    another_file_4_nnoot_ok.sh

$ shopt -s extglob
$ cp -v +(*not_ok*) somedir/
another_file_1_not_ok.sh -> somelib/another_file_1_not_ok.sh
another_file_2_not_ok.sh -> somelib/another_file_2_not_ok.sh
another_file_3_not_ok.sh -> somelib/another_file_3_not_ok.sh
```

To remove the files except the one containing this pattern, do

```
$ rm -v !(*not_ok*) 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: thanks for the update, but does rm completely removes the files from the system? I meant to say i want every file who doesn`t have "1_ok" string to be sent to another directory. Just in case i have too use it someday.

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man: Then why do you suggest deletion, `rm` completely removes the from the file-system. Try using `mv`

Comment: I typed without thinking straight. Thanks a lot mate.
I'm going to update the main post.

Comment: I have another question here.
When i tried to using the mv command it moved the files just fine, however when i try to move files from a folder to a sub-folder and error message appears saying it can`t move the folder into itself, even though it moved all other files just fine. IS there any way to avoid that error to occur?

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man, Add a `2>/dev/null` at the end of the command, to suppress the error message